# Responsive design doesn't working tailwind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

Hi I've got problem with responsive design because it's working in browser, when im changing browser size to small site is changing but when i'm going on site using mobile device or inspect element tool it's not changing. Here is demo of website: https://horrorfiles.htw.pl
I'm using tailwind css and react js, i made lots of projects using that and thats my first case.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to read proper documentation and then apply the usual breakpoints for responsiveness here is the documentation of breakpoints and everything looks on good on your site.

[enter link description here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#using-custom-breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one meta tag in your HTML head, just copy paste it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're using the breakpoint prefixes to target mobile devices instead of designing for mobile then using breakpoint to target larger screens. Tailwind's documentation has this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design.

Answer (score 0):

If you have built the project from the beginning from create-react-app/cli, you should not face this issue. You must not have forgotten to do Tailwind init. It's hard to debug from the words as you say you have followed all the steps, like other projects. Something might have changed in the commits.

Share the GitHub link to review the issue of past a code snippet.